# Where are global functions defined in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

After an extensive google search I can't seem to find where functions (such as `url()`) are defined in Twig. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ahh never mind, after a quick look through the code base I found the directory where twig global functions are defined:

> Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension

Answer (score 0):

The default functions (and filters) defined by Twig and available for any application which installs Twig as a dependency are defined in the `twig/lib/Twig/Extension/` directory inside your `vendor/` directory (most of the functions are defined in the `Core.php` extension). These functions are documented [in this page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation).

Besides, the Symfony full-stack framework defines some proprietary extensions for Twig to augment its features. They are defined in the `symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/` directory inside your `vendor/` directory. And they are documented [in this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html).